# How do I make two Text() views the same dynamic font size in SwiftUI, maximizing the font size?

Tags: swiftui, font-size

Reacting to the user’s device rotation and taking into account the various screen sizes of iPhones and iPads i want two (for example) Text() Views to have the maximum possible font size without truncating and without line wrapping. I tried a lot, lastly this and nothing worked.

```
struct MinimumHeightPreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: CGFloat = 1_000.0
    static func reduce(value: inout CGFloat, nextValue: () -> CGFloat) {
        value = min(value, nextValue())
    }
}

struct DetermineHeight: View{
    typealias Key = MinimumHeightPreferenceKey
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            Color.clear
                .anchorPreference(key: Key.self, value: .bounds) {
                    anchor in proxy[anchor].size.height
                }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var minTextHeight: CGFloat = 75
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack(alignment: VerticalAlignment.firstTextBaseline){
                Text("Short Text")
                    .frame(maxHeight: minTextHeight)
                    .overlay(DetermineHeight())
                    .border(Color.red)
                    .scaledToFit()
                Text("This is a considerably longer text. ideally it should also reduce the shorter Text's size so they both look the same.")
                //.frame(minHeight: 1.0, maxHeight: minTextHeight)
                    .overlay(DetermineHeight())
                    .border(Color.green)
            }
            .font(.title)
            .lineLimit(1)
            .minimumScaleFactor(0.25)
            .onPreferenceChange(DetermineHeight.Key.self) {
                minTextHeight = $0
            }
            Text("minHeight = \(minTextHeight)")
        }
    }
}
```

The boxes turn out the same hight, but the texts aren’t adjusted. (Plus: if I uncomment that line I the boxes don’t resize at all. Huh?)

[image]

Am I trying to do the impossible?